# All links in search engines redirect to home page

Tags: redirect, product-view, seo

A click on google search results on all products on my site directs you to the homepage rather than the actual product page.

Why is it happening and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Hello IdyAghe, welcome to Magento stackexchange. What have you tried so far ? On what point, you are finding difficulties ? Please be more specific on your question. Thank you.

Comment: try posting here also : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It can be a number of things. At a minimum, we'll need to know the response header to even begin to help, and maybe some more explanation about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely related to you changing the domain or switching your store to https only by setting the unsecure domain to be https. When you do this and enable the Magento option that forces the base domain to be correct, it redirects all requests to the home page.

If you changed the domain name then something like this in your .htaccess or vhost should do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com$1 [R=302,L]
```

If you forced https, then in your HTTP vhost (port 80) simply redirect all requests to https.

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.com$1 [R=302,L]
```

NB: In either case, once you are happy it's working, change the 302 to 301.

Comment: Addition: to debug the issue, opening the network tab in your browser console (F12 in most cases) helps to see what the original request is that has been redirected. You will find out that this request does not match the configured base URL.